# Determination level of agglomerative hierarchy clustering

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, data-mining

I am going to cluster my data (trajectory data) using AHC. Could you please let me know how I can determine the level of AHC?

Answer (score 0):

The aim of clustering should be that the clusters themselves should be far away from each other and the points within a cluster should be as close to each other as possible.

**AIM:** This is another way of saying that we have to minimize intra-cluster distance and maximize inter-cluster distance.

For this, we used various purity measures such as:

1. Davies-Boulding index: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davies%E2%80%93Bouldin_index
2. Silhouette value: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_(clustering)
   Or you can come with your functions where the AIM is achieved.

After every iteration, you can calculate the purity of your made clusters and stop when you reach minima

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am familiar with external and internal measures. You mean, I must perform AHC and then use these measures to determine the cluster number?

Comment: Yes. Try one iteration of AHC and then compute the purity. There can be 3 stopping criteria here: 1. Define a target purity value - when acheived stop AHC. drawback is you have yo decide on a purity value which can be difficult. 2. Store current cluster seperately and redo AHC over a copy of current clusters. Compute purity of new clusters. Compare both purity and stop when purity decreases. 3. Fix the number of iterations directly (easiest but bit random) I would personally suggest first one